# Vuejs Not Printing Data Returned In The Method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can successfully get data to the console but data is not printing on the screen. I'm trying to get the list of data.

I could return the data on the console. I didn't understand what is wrong. Everything looks fine.

Template:

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header pb-0 px-3">
        <h6 class="mb-0">Personnel Information</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body pt-4 p-3" >
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item border-0 d-flex p-4 mb-2 bg-gray-100 border-radius-lg"  v-for="personnel in personnels" :key="personnel.id">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column" >
               <h6 class="mb-3 text-sm"> {{personnel.name}} {{personnel.surname}}</h6>
              <span class="mb-2 text-xs">
                Title:
                <span class="text-dark font-weight-bold ms-sm-2">{{personnel.title}}</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ms-auto text-end">
              <a class="btn btn-link text-danger text-gradient px-3 mb-0" href="javascript:;">
                <i class="far fa-trash-alt me-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Delete
              </a>
              <a class="btn btn-link text-dark px-3 mb-0" href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt text-dark me-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit
              </a>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Method:

```
<script>

import axios from 'axios';
export default {
name: "personnel-card",
    data(){
        return {
            personnels:[],
        }
    },
    methods: {
getPersonnels(){
             const path = 'https://localhost:7022/api/Personnels';
             axios.get(path)
                 .then((res)=> {
                     console.log(res);
                     this.personnels = res.data.data.personnels;
                 })
                 .catch((error) => {
                     console.error(error);
                 })

         },
        
    },
    created(){
            this.getPersonnels();
    }

}
</script>
```

Here the console:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it has to be `res.data.data`, not `res.data.data.personnels`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that within the method, you are not traversing through the results properly, It looks like object within an another object as a list. So res.data.data would give you access to the array, but I'm not sure how you would use
'this.personnel.name' on an array. Please share how the what is inside the array for an accurate answer

Comment: `res.data.data` solved the problem instead of `res.data.data.personnels`